# How to maintain sr no on orderitem?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created sr_no__c field on orderitem obj with number data type and have default value 0.

whenever new orderitem is inserted than this index should increase..??

```
trigger updatesrno on OrderItem (before insert) {

        /* for(integer i = 0; i < trigger.new.size(); i++){

             if(trigger.new[i].Quantity >= 1){

                 trigger.new[i].sr_no__c = trigger.new[i].sr_no__c + 1 ; 
             }

         */
             for(OrderItem o : trigger.new ){

             integer j=0;

                 if(o.Quantity >= 1){

                     o.sr_no__c = o.sr_no__c + 1 ; 
                 }
             }
         }
```

but it not work

Comment: It won't work because you need to query the latest serial number from the latest record. But this is hell a lot complex if you consider deletion.

Comment: Use auto number fields.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve the functionality : -

1. you can create **sr_no__c** field as auto number,then whenever one record is inserted the number filed will automatically increased.
2. if you want to use it in trigger , then before assigning the value to **sr_no__c**  field you need to do one query on the **OrderItem**  object like below : -

   List lst_OrderItem= [SELECT sr_no__c FROM OrderItem order by sr_no__c desc];

from there you can find the latest number and from there you can assign the incremental values to **sr_no__c** field.